# Problems with IE - Webpage does not load well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have my website completely finished and running well in Google Chrome, Firefox, and other browsers except in Internet Explorer.

the menu is not seen, it is broken. The margins are not applied, the text is totally without form, it is as if no bookstore is being loaded. The website is created with bootstrap 3.6 Jquery is used to handle most of the effects of the page.

Do you know if IE does not support jquery, bootstrap or any other library? All libraries on my site are loaded locally.

The content of the page is loaded by means of php, since all the content is in database. It works well in other browsers but not in IE. The idea is that it works well in everyone.

I use this css files in my head

```
                  <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="de">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Nivamedia | Webdesign, Online Marketing, Mobile Apps</title>
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <meta name="keywords" content="">
                <meta name="description" content="">

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/et-line-font.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo_themes/default/default.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                <!-- <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

                         </head>
```

This is my navigation menu

```
                      <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="50">
                        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-121888387-1"></script>
                            <script>
                              window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                              function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                              gtag('js', new Date());
                              gtag('config', 'UA-121888387-1');
                            </script>
                        <!-- preloader section -->

                        <div class="preloader">
                            <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-circle">
                               <div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
                               <div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- navigation section -->
                        <section class="navbar navbar-fixed-top custom-navbar bg-trans" role="navigation" id="navbar_menu">
                            <div class="container" id="navbar_container">
                             <div class="navbar-header" id="mobile_version_collapse-in" style="background-color: white !important;">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="toggle_button">
                            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="nav-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/nivaLogo2.png" alt="logo" title="Nivamedia" id="main_logo"></a>
                    </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu_collapse">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="list_options">

                            <li class="list_options_Li"><a href="#" class="smoothScroll itemLi"></a></li>

                             <li class="list_options_Li" id="first_li_main"><a href="leistungen.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">Leistungen</a></li>
                            <li class="list_options_Li" id="second_li_main"><a href="referenzen.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">Referenzen</a></li>
                            <li class="list_options_Li" id="third_li_main"><a href="#agentur" class="smoothScroll itemLi">Agentur</a></li>
                            <li class="list_options_Li" id="fourth_li_main"><a href="kontakt.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">Kontakt</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                   </section>
```

and I have this js libraries at the end of the body:

```
                     <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
                                <script src="js/sweetalert.js"></script>
```

All other pages of the website has the same problem.

Comment: Try adding this to your `<head>` section: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: You are likely having CSS support issues. go through all your css and verify it against http://caniuse.com/ .

Comment: @Tico Yes, the page already has it, but still it does not work well.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer are we talking about here? Bootstrap 3 supports  IE version 8 and above

Comment: I tried removing the meta tag where the IE = edge is but it still does not work. I have version 11.0.96 of IE, I do not use nor sass, n react, angular, etc.

Comment: Then it's probably not an issue with BS. Which jQuery plugins are you using for the header?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the browser's console?

Comment: It's strange because I created other pages previously with bootstrap, pages very similar to this one and I have not had that problem with IE

Comment: @PatrickHund No, that's the strangest thing. The console does not show any error.

Comment: OK, sorry, I don't think I can help, being on a Mac and all :-)

Comment: There's zero way to help with the information provided.

Comment: did you use a viewport meta tag?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I use a viewport meta tag I have edited my question and add more information

Comment: Theres something wrong with the navbar in IE

Comment: @DaveNewton I have added some code to my question.

Comment: @WaynePhipps 
I do not know if it's just a problem with the header nav-bar because the rest of the page is also unconfigured.

Comment: First thing I would do is disable scripts and see if base html page renders correctly. Brings back memories of older IE days where it was an every day occurrence fighting IE specific issues. Used to be sites dedicated to *"IE Hacks"*

Comment: It is related to the navbar, you can set it to `display: none` and the rest is no longer pushed down

Comment: It seems like there are a couple duplicate `id`... Have a look at [Markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fnivamedia.ch%2F) - I can't tell if that's the issue... But it should be fixed anyway. Start with this. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I start with that

Comment: @WaynePhipps I'll try that to check the results.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette 
I have removed all duplicate ids and still the problem, the page in IE remains the same

Comment: @WaynePhipps I tried to display:none the navbar but that's not worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answer works for you but there seems to be a problem with your bootstrap.css file: `https://nivamedia.ch/css/bootstrap.min.css` (v3.3.5)

replace this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

with an updated version of bootstrap (3.3.7)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get in IE:

[image]

Also, I should make you aware that the files you are hosting are either corrupt or not encoded using UTF-8. Check the sites header is using UTF-8 if they are it's likely the bootstrap.css is corrupt, try downloading a new file and reuploading it.

Here is your bootstrap.css: `https://nivamedia.ch/css/bootstrap.min.css`

[image]

There is a lot of ��������������������� within.

Comment: You know what, that happened to me a few weeks ago with those files even the page was not running in chrome or in other browsers, but I downloaded the files again, delete the old ones and place the new ones. In chrome and other browsers it worked but in IE it did not. 
But I will try what you say, to see if upgrading to bootstrap 3.7 works finally.

Comment: Okay, let us know if that works. **The bootstrap file is the only one I found corrupt for now.** This probably may not solve much but it will help browsers encode files properly: It looks like you don't have a default charset in the response headers. It should show `Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8` . I don't use nginx so I don't know how you'd change it but you can search for a way. If this isn't set, the browser may use a different encoding. It also looks like the server is delivering GZIP so I'm not sure if there's a server issue deflating the file or if it's an EOL formatting issue.

Comment: I changed the bootstrap css but now I jotted jquery error and it does not let me open the page because the debugger keeps it on pause, this only in IE, in other browsers it works fine.

Comment: It seemed fine when I tested it. Try following what errors you see. I wasn't getting any but I can have a look later when I'm free.

Comment: I've had another look and everything seems perfect with no errors at all in both Internet Explorer and IE (Edge). Everything responds as it should and the styles are displaying properly. You may have to just clear the browsers cache.

Comment: Also, the following files are corrupt `css/font-awesome.min.css` and `css/animate.min.css`. I recommend re-downloading them from the original source sites and re-uploading and open them in Chrome, make sure there aren't any �����Ð‰E or �������� displaying. It could be the GZIP causing minified code to deform, I don't know.

Comment: This is what I'm getting as corrupt files https://ibb.co/d7EQjq affecting ALL minified CSS and JS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your recommendations, I have taken them into account, I will download the files that you told me again and I will upload them again. I will be constantly monitoring the website and doing testing. 
Thank you very much, you have been very helpful in finding the solution to this problem.